# Setting the position and zOrder of the items in Items control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

Is there some guidance / example on how to make an items control that will provide output similar to Win8 TaskBar showing its icons?

For example, lets say that I have the following collection of items:

```
Name   GroupIndex
-------------------
Item1       1
Item2       2
Item3       3
Item4       3
Item5       4
Item6       5
Item7       5
Item8       5
```

i need to display these items in a horizontal orientation, grouped by their index, where we will get output like: full size Item1, then full size Item2, then Items3 and 4 overlaped like cards, then Item4, then Item6, 7 and 8 overlapped, etc.

Similar behavior has W8 TaskBar for icons, but the difference is that it can display max 3 overlapped icons, while I need to have more than that, and I also need to be able to template them differently (ex different color).

Simply speaking, I need to somehow say:

```
- show first in normal size
- check if second is in the same group as previous
  - Yes: make it overlap the first, but with lower zOrder
  - No: show second in normal size
- etc
```

The control also needs to have scrollbars, to scroll the content if required. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a view model that realizes the grouping. Then use a horizontal StackPanel as the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel and display item groups with one or more elements.

Comment: @Clemens Well, I asked the question how to achieve this. How will I display item groups? And what kind of groups are you talking about? Can you give any example? I was speaking about the flat collection, but if I understand you correctly, you are speaking about the hierarchical collection?

Comment: Sure, a hierarchical collection with two levels. An outer ItemsControl that displays groups, and an inner ItemsControl that displays the items of a Group.